# Unrelated "because"

Tags: word-usage

A student uses the following sentence:

> I love strong coffee, because there are coffee plantations in Kenya.

The reason *(because X)* is unrelated to the statement.
Is there a term for this?

Answer (score 2):

It is a ***non sequitur***

> /nɒn ˈsɛkwɪtə/
>
> noun
>
> a conclusion or statement that does not logically follow from the
>   previous argument or statement.
>
> [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=non%20sequitur%20meaning)

Comment: /nɒn ˈsɛkwɪt**ɚ/**

Comment: It's Latin for _(It) does not follow_; _non_ means 'not' and _sequitur_ means 'It follows'. Same root as _sequence, consequence,_ and _consecutive_, all about things following other things -- temporally, one after another, or on a road, literally moving.